# Does openssl DTLS 1.0.2k takes fragmented input and reassemble fragmented packets?

Tags: ssl, openssl, udp

I am facing an issue where DTLS handshake packets are greater than 1500 bytes and I do fragment to make sure it is less than 1500 bytes. The fragmentation is as per RFC dictated. Now, when I check captured pcap, fragment and reassembled when complete packet received. However DTLS SSL_connect function when I feed fragmented packets. The question here, should I reconstruct complete packet and give it to SSL_connect function?

Answer (score 0):

As I read [the current(?) draft](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-tls-dtls13-30.html#rfc.section.3.1.2):

> 3.1.2. Message Size TLS and DTLS handshake messages can be quite large (in theory up to 2^24-1 bytes, in practice many kilobytes). By
>   contrast, UDP datagrams are often limited to less than 1500 bytes if
>   IP fragmentation is not desired. In order to compensate for this
>   limitation, **each DTLS handshake message may be fragmented over several
>   DTLS records**, each of which is intended to fit in a single IP
>   datagram. Each DTLS handshake message contains both a fragment offset
>   and a fragment length. Thus, a recipient in possession of all bytes of
>   a handshake message can reassemble the original unfragmented message.